# sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed when inserting after select

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am doing a `select()` from a SQLite database and then an `insert()`:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///testdb.db')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
test = Table('test', metadata, autoload=True)

# Select all from pending_data
sel = select([test])
res = engine.execute(sel)

print res

# do an insert into pending_data
test.insert()\
    .values(info='blah')\
    .execute()
```

When my code executes the insert line, I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed
```

However, if I convert my res into a list like so:

```
res = list(engine.execute(sel))
```

My code runs fine.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has two concepts that one must be aware of: connections and engines. An engine can support many simultaneous connections. In your example you bind the table to an engine. Now, whenever you call `.execute`, a new connection is created for each single query that you execute. But sqlite3 only allows 1 simultaneous "connection".

The best way to fix this is to create the connection and use it explicitly instead of the automatically created connections of the engine; and to use the connection with the `with` statement, which ensures that the connection would be closed at the end of the block:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///testdb.db')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
test = Table('test', metadata, autoload=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    # Select all from pending_data
    sel = select([test])
    res = connection.execute(sel)

    # do an insert into pending_data
    connection.execute(test.insert().values(info='blah'))
```

---

To understand this behaviour, the error occurs because you are holding an active cursor within an implicitly created and held collection (this is referred to by the `res` variable; until you consume it, or close it, or drop references to it, the cursor and thus the connection will be alive, and the database will be locked).

When you execute `list(res)`, you are consuming the cursor and it gets closed by SQLAlchemy; the same would happen if the reference count of the result would drop to 0.

You can also try the following to see the point, they'd work as you expected:

```
res = engine.execute(sel)
print(res)
res.close()  # close explicitly
```

or

```
res = engine.execute(sel)
print(res)
del res  # drop the only reference to res
```

Thus always consume the ResultProxy entirely or close it explicitly, or drop references to it when you're done.

And this is not a problem if you reuse the same *connection*; only whenever you create a new connection to an sqlite3 database (postgresql, mysql, oracle etc handle this fine too).

Comment: What does `drop references to it` mean?

Comment: Objects are deallocated when no names or other objects point to them

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error when I have tried to post entries for a table, I was using the new syntax of `sqlachmey`, I have forgot to add the table calss name while I used `select` so I wrote it `select().where...` instead of `select(tbaleNameClass).where...` so I got this `ResourceClosedError`.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

So the only thing I had to do is to write the syntax correctly so instead of writing

```py
  query = select().where(
        Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)
```

write

```py
  query = select(Assessment).where(
        Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)
```

> `Assessment` is the table class name

So In case anyone of you get the same error check first that you write things correctly :).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had similar problem. I checked the connection object, I can see that the object has an attribute: "closed" which becomes True after previous select query. So I recreate the connection again. And that works.